# How to get user who ran interaction

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have searched arround for a while for this but can't seem to find an answer. Does anyone know how to get the user who ran the interactions nickname, username, and user id? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction?scrollTo=user)/[`member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction?scrollTo=member) properties of [`Interaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction).

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    // Making sure the interaction is a command
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return false;

    await interaction.reply(`Hello, ${interaction.user.tag}!`)
})
```

Comment: `interaction.user.tag` is neither the nick, username, or id. It is the [`user.tag`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=tag). You may want to change that in your answer to better respond to the actual question.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest fetching the user, and then getting all the information you want.

```js
const interactionUser = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(interaction.user.id)

const nickName = interactionUser.nickname
const userName = interactionUser.user.username
const userId = interactionUser.id
```

Not fetching the user explicitly may lead to missing information.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go, since it's easier to get all the information in one go.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to make another fetch-request in order to get the nickname of the user who ran the interaction. The interaction sends a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMember) instance which contains all the data of the user who sent the interaction and which can be accessed through `interaction.member`. So in your code example you could do so:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
// Making sure the interaction is a command
if (!interaction.isCommand()) return false;

await interaction.reply(`Hello, ${interaction.member.displayName}!`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
// Making sure the interaction is a command
if (!interaction.isCommand()) return false;

await interaction.reply(`Hello, <@${interaction.member.id}>!`)
})
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).